# how to rename wp-login.php, wp-admin.php and wp-folder on wordpress?

Tags: php, web, wordpress

how to rename wp-login.php, wp-admin.php and wp-folder on wordpress? I want to remove all the wp prefixes from everywhere on my website please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not healthy to rename them. If you mean renamie on url with renaming, you can do that with [url rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), but this is also not an easy stuff. As a different way, I suggest you to use a plugin for doing your work. This plugin is called [All In One Seo Pack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/). You can convert your url structure in different format. This plugin makes your urls SEO friendly

Comment: no i dint try it i am serching for looking for that perticular solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can folllow below link
http://www.trickspanda.com/2014/01/hide-wordpress-admin-url/
To learn wp theme delopment: http://prowpexpert.com/

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my customized version of [wordpress](https://github.com/ziobru/no_prefix_WordPress_setup). I've included a script I've made that will remove the wp- prefix from wordpress files and folders. It's under development but works fine. Test it on your localhost before use this modified version of wordpress in production.